# Does Google bill for the IP addresses that are bound to stopped VMs?

Tags: ip-address, google-compute-engine

Any idea whether Google bills for IP that are attached to stopped VMs, and is it the same rate as for an unused IP?
(which actually makes sense).

Answer (score 3):

When the instance is stopped it is assumed that eventually it will be started again. As such, the static IP is still attached to an instance and will not be charged. You can go through this [link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/pricing#ipaddress) which has information about the static IP charges.

Comment: **Static IP address (assigned but unused) $0.010 / h**

Answer (score 0):

https://cloud.google.com/compute/pricing#ipaddress says:

- Static IP address (assigned but unused) - $0.010 / h
- Static IP address (assigned and in use) - No charge
- Ephemeral IP address (attached to instance or forwarding rule) -  No charge

Find out unused:

```
bash# gcloud compute addresses list
NAME                     REGION        ADDRESS         STATUS
artifactory-2-vm         europe-west1  10.132.x.x      IN_USE
artifactory-2-vm-pub     europe-west1  35.210.x.x      RESERVED
artifactory-2-vm-public  europe-west1  35.210.x.x      IN_USE
```

Remove unused:

```
gcloud compute addresses delete artifactory-2-vm-pub --region=europe-west1
```